# Does ZendAMF compress data automatically when sending from flash client to the zend amd end point?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, zend-framework, arrays

If I sent two strings from my flash movie using actionscript 3...

var name:String = "Name of my item";
var description:String = "Description of my item here";

var byteArray:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(mySprite);

Do i have to compress the byte array using as3 byteArray.compress() or does that even have any effect on this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to compress the bytearray to send it over the wire.  However, when I send bytes over the wire, I usually Base64 encode them into a string because sometimes the backend won't play nice with a raw byte array.